# Trouble populating ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I am having trouble understanding why my code is behaving as it does. What I do is create an ArrayList of a custom class. Populate the class object then add it to the ArrayList. I then reuse the class object and populate it with new values and add it to the ArrayList EXCEPT the first one gets overwritten by the second?? Is there some sort of internal pointer or the arraylist isn't yet committed that could cause this?

Here I declare my ArrayList

```
private ArrayList<LiftData> arrylst_LiftData = new ArrayList<LiftData>();
```

Then I create my custom data object (just a class with some properties)

```
LiftData obj_LData = new LiftData();
```

Some code not shown populates it with valid data and I add it to the ArrayList

```
arrylst_LiftData.add(obj_LData);
```

Now at this point the code goes throught the loop populating the obj_LData with new values and then it gets added to the arraylist but the first one is gone???

If I add the second line shown under the ArrayList add it all works???

```
arrylst_LiftData.add(obj_LData);
obj_LData = new LiftData();
```

Can someone please edjumakate me on what is going on?

Comment: In my mind it is the latter. I am re-using the same object in two contexts. Like a piece of paper. I write some answers on it and hand it off to the teacher. The teacher gives it back and I erase the writing and do another assignment and give that to the teacher. In my mind the teacher photocopied the first so what harm is there in my reusing the piece of paper?

Comment: Your mind is wrong. Adding an object to an ArrayList copies nothing. It just adds a pointer to the ArrayList to the same thing that obj_LData is pointing to.

Comment: Exactly. I was thinking it was ByVal and it is ByRef. So as othyers pointed out the ArrayLisrt doesn't create new memory and allocate it holds a pointer. TOTALLY MY MISUNDERSTANDING.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An `ArrayList`, like all Java collections -- indeed, all variables in Java -- contains references to objects, not the objects themselves. It sounds like you've only ever created a single `LiftData` object, and are filling the `ArrayList` with multiple references to it. Each time you change its data, every object in the `ArrayList` will change -- because they're all the same object.

This is in contrast to what you'd get if you used essentially the same syntax in C++; inserting into a `vector` is going to create a copy of the object, and you could indeed modify the object, re-add it, and get two different objects in the `vector`. But Java doesn't work that way: all variables of object type are essentially pointers.

In your loop that populates the list, you need to create a new `LiftData` object each time around.

Answer (score 3):

You are just adding a reference to the object in the ArrayList. You later modify that object, so of course the one in the array list is modified (it's the same object).

With obj_LData = new LiftData(); you are creating a new object that it's different to the one in the ArrayList, that's why it works.

```
LiftData obj_LData = new LiftData();
LiftData obj_LData2 = obj_LData;
```

Here, obj_LData and obj_LData2 point to the same object. If you change a property of one of them, the other will be changed too.

Answer (score 1):

I think what is happening is as follows:
Because you don't 'new' your custom object, the variable you're changing (for the second element of the ArrayList) is actually the first element in the array list, because it points to the same place in memory (by reference).

When you 'new' it, you make a new space in memory, and give it a new pointer. So the first element that you've added now points to a different place to that which you edit for the second element.

Reusing the variable is fine, but it needs newing before changing and adding, because the pointers will be the same otherwise.

```
LiftData toAdd;
ArrayList<LiftData> list = new ArrayList<LiftData>();
for (int i=0;i<5;i++) {
   //Without this line here, the pointers to all the elements of the array list will the same.
   //This means that they will have the same values too
   toAdd = new LiftData();
   //init lift data values
   list.add(toAdd);
}
```